# Why I can't import team from nba_py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just wanna run a very simple python script by using nba_py. I already install the nba_py package. But it's not work.[My Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VdzT.png)

The console always shows ImpoetError[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtdeZ.png)

Comment: Did you install `nba_py`(`pip install nba_py`)?

Comment: And are you sure you do not have any other `nba_py.py` in the same directory from where you are running the code?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you are doing `from nba_py import ...` inside `nba_py`.

Comment: yes, I already install nba_py by using pip install nba_py. I think maybe is my file name's problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have to rename your file name from *nba_py* to others, like *test_for_nba_py* ? It's up to you :).

Because your file name is *nba_py*, then when you

```
from nba_py import team
```

It will not check module team in nba_py package.

Comment: thanks, I change the file name. And the error didn't coming out. But there are no output. the Debug Console just shows <nba_py.team.TeamPassTracking instance at 0x04A65AA8>

Comment: Are you trying to use *print(knicks)* ?, it's expected to see something like you applied.  Print object will just show <xxxxx instance at xxxx>(if the object don't provide custom \_\_str\_\_ method)

Comment: Yes, I tried to use print(knicks),but just show<xxxx instance at xxxx>. Actually I just follow the tutorial in (http://blog.yhat.com/posts/visualize-nba-pipelines.html). They didn't print anything and they can see the exactly table. But I can't, I don't know why.

Comment: Err.. I have read that page.  They can see the exactly table is not because they are using print(knicks)...May be you can do something like *knicks.passes_made().head(10)*? note that if an object's __str__ method is not defined custom, try to simply do *print(object)* will not get much information that we need.